# Engines that predict the outcome of current matches in real-time

Tags: analysis

I'm looking for an engine that will allow a full game to be loaded in an attempt to visualize the major turning points in the game. Are there engines that predict the outcome of current matches in real-time?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. But check out (http://chessbomb.com/site/) to follow live games from top level tournaments with an engine running next to the board if you want to follow the evaluation of the current position in every game.

Comment: @RauanSagit: Exactly how is the question unclear? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any chess program ([Crafty](http://www.craftychess.com/), for instance) will do that.  Use analysis mode.  Key in the move, and it will produce a score.  The score implies how well one side is doing.

Comment: [houdini](http://www.cruxis.com/chess/houdini.htm) via [Arena](http://http://www.playwitharena.com) too..